# How to structure the selection of one, two, or three choices in an argparse argument efficiently?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I am designing an argparse-based command line program, and one of the arguments that must be made asks the user to select one or more out of a total of three choices for the format of an output graph. If the user does not mention this argument within the command line, then by default, this argument outputs all three types of the output graphs.

So, the argument itself looks more or less like this:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BobsProgram = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog= "BobsProgram")
    BobsProgram.description= "This code analyzes these inputs, and will output one or more graphs of your choosing."

    BobsProgram.add_argument("-output_graph", choices= ["pie", "bar", "scatter"], default= all, nargs= "+",
    help= "Unless otherwise indicated, the output graphs will be given in the pie, bar, and scatter forms.")
```

So, after I ran the `args= BobsProgram.parse_args()` line and started to dispatch my arguments, I wanted it set up so that the user could type in their choices in order they wanted. I have only found it possible to make the command line program function when I set up seven conditional blocks:

```
if args.output_graph == ["pie"]:
    ##format the output file as a pie chart
elif args.output_graph == ["bar"]:
    ##format the output file as a bar chart
elif args.output_graph == ["scatter"]:
    ##format the output as a scatter chart
elif args.output_graph == ["pie","bar"] and ["bar", "pie"]:
    ##format the output as pie and bar charts
elif args.output_graph == ["pie","scatter"] and ["scatter","pie"]:
    ##format the output as pie and scatter charts
elif args.output_graph == ["bar", "scatter"] and ["scatter","bar"]:
    ##format the output as bar and scatter charts
else:
    ##format the output as bar, pie, and scatter charts
```

Ultimately, although the code works, it does not seem very Pythonic, as I must replicate a lot of the same code within each conditional block. How can I amend this to make it more efficient?

Comment: Don't  worry about efficiency.  A parser is run once at the start of the script.  It's more important that it is user friendly and clear.  What is `all`?  Consider tests like `'bar' in args.output_graph` (since that attribute is a list of these strings).  However that won't respond to user's order.

Comment: @hpaulj `all` is a keyword which, from what I understand, encapsulates all the choices provided. Also, what do you mean by testing `'bar'`?

Comment: `all` isn't an `argparse` keyword.  It might may make sense if defined as a list of the choices.

Comment: @hpaulj so, instead of giving `all` as the default, should I give `["pie","bar", "scatter"]` as the default?

Comment: If your code didn't already define `all = ["pie","bar", "scatter"]`, it would expect a `NameError, 'all' not defined'.

Comment: @hpaulj No, `all` is a built-in function. It would run, just give unexpected results.

Comment: @SethMMorton. you are right.  I forgot about the Python `all`.  I'm more likely to use the numpy function or method.  So it doesn't raise an error,but also doesn't serve the intended purpose.

Comment: @SethMMorton I misunderstood the proper usage of the keyword `all`. I have thus replaced my `default= all` in my argument set up to `default= ["pie","bar","scatter"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter then you could do:

```
alist = args.your_name
if 'foo' in alist:
   # do foo
elif 'bar' in alist:
   # do bar
# etc
```

If the user provided order matters then the something like this:

```
for fn in alist:
    if fn in ['foo']:    # or `fn == 'foo'`
        # do foo
    elif fn in ['bar']:
        # do bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like:

```
for arg in args.output_graph:
    if arg == 'pie':
        #add_pie_chart()
    if arg == 'bar':
        #add_bar_chart()
    if arg == 'scatter':
        #add_scatter_plot()
```

The graph functionality now is only called once for each chart.  This should work as long as your add chart functions play relatively nice with each other, i.e. all get added to a master canvas before results are displayed.